# Getting the object obtained from asynchronous $http service in angularJS to be accessible globally in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am working using Angular JS. I am trying to get a json object obtained using $http service to be accessible in a $scope variable. Inside all the asynchronous AJAX ($http.get()) calls, if I try to print the data obtained stored inside a $scope variable and print it, it works successfully and shows me the expected data. But outside scope of the asynchronous method, the same $scope variable assigned with data obtained loses hold of it and prints undefined.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('chariot', ['ngRoute', 'ngFileUpload']);
    app.factory('getTestcaseFactory', ['$http', '$routeParams', '$q', function($http, $routeParams, $q) {
       return {
              list: function(){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('/testcase/' + $routeParams.testcase)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject("Error fetching XML file: " + status + ' ' + JSON.stringify(headers));
                });
                return deferred.promise;
              }
            }; 
    }
    ]);
app.controller('testcaseCapCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'getTestcaseFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, getTestcaseFactory) {
    $scope.myjsonobj = '';
    var fetchTestcaseDetails = function() {
    getTestcaseFactory.list()
        .then(
            function(data) {
                $scope.xml.file = data;
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json($scope.xml.file);
                $scope.xml.json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2);
                $scope.model = jsonObj;
                console.log($scope.model);//PRINTS THE RIGHT DATA
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
    }
fetchTestcaseDetails();
console.log($scope.model); //Prints undefined
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time

```
console.log($scope.model);
```

executes, the `$http` request would have not gone through yet, and this is why it prints undefined. Once the `$http` request is done, your `$scope.model` will update accordingly. You can test this by using a `$timeout`

```
$timeout(function () {
    console.log($scope.model);
}, 5000);
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout` in your controller.

Comment: While this answer is correctly pointing out the nature of the problem, that 5000 timeout is completely arbitrary, and will work only sometimes, depending on how long the actual call takes. Print it in the callback, or use an angular $watch mechanism to make the code more data-oriented, and less dependent on timings.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Moldovan! I too figured out may be I have to use a timer to wait till the $http service completes with data obtained. $timeout does the work. Thanks Again!

Comment: Glad to help my friend!

Comment: @doldt Can you may be share a plunker here to show your way of resolving this issue by using $watch? Somewhere I saw the $watch approach, but I failed to implement it for the resolution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This saves my day! $timeout to the rescue. Thanks @Dan Moldovan for the answer! As the $http service is asynchronous, we have to set a timer to wait for a time interval till the point the data is really received in the promise.success section and then it can be assigned to a variable inside $scope.

```
var app = angular.module('chariot', ['ngRoute', 'ngFileUpload']);
        app.factory('getTestcaseFactory', ['$http', '$routeParams', '$q', function($http, $routeParams, $q) {
           return {
                  list: function(){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.get('/testcase/' + $routeParams.testcase)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.reject("Error fetching XML file: " + status + ' ' + JSON.stringify(headers));
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                  }
                }; 
        }
        ]);
    app.controller('testcaseCapCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'getTestcaseFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, getTestcaseFactory) {
        var fetchTestcaseDetails = function() {
        getTestcaseFactory.list()
            .then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.xml.file = data;
                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                    var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json($scope.xml.file);
                    $scope.xml.json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2);
                    $scope.model = jsonObj;
                    console.log($scope.model);//PRINTS THE RIGHT DATA
                },
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
        }
    fetchTestcaseDetails();
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope.model); //Prints the Data now
    }, 2000);
    }]);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, even though it might work *most of the time*. See my answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted so far are **fundemantally wrong**, as they depend on an arbitrary timeout, and nothing guarantees that the async answer will be available by then.

As I suggested in a comment above, here are 2 more data/event-driven solutions.

1. You either only print in the callback function *(which you're already doing in your example)*
2. Or since you're using angular anyway, you can set up a watch *(which in the background uses a not-too-nice dirty checking solution, but at least it's abstracted away from your code)*

If you want to run a function called `processData` once the data is available, solution 1 you already do in your example, see this line:

```
console.log($scope.model);//PRINTS THE RIGHT DATA
```

Here you could call any other function to trigger the continuation of the process, just call whatever function:

```
console.log($scope.model);//PRINTS THE RIGHT DATA
processData();
```

Using angular's $watch mechanism (2.):

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(){return $scope.model;},
    function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue != null){
            console.log($scope.model);
            processData();
        }
})
```

This will print the data when it is available after the async callback, and the program will continue with processing from then.

Comment: This is cool enough. My first approach was this only, to use the $watch approach. But then I didn't know what exactly I should have mentioned as the first parameter to the watch method, so I ended up giving up on this approach and instead, take on the timeout approach. Anyways, @doldt, thanks for the suggestion and help. I would implement this right away.